# Angular Router getting URL matching a sub-tree

Tags: angular

I want to write a Component that handles all the sub-paths of a given URL base.  For example:

```
/text/123
/text/something
/text/this/is/a/subpath
```

So I discovered I can set up my route table to get all those URLs to go to my component like this:

```
const route: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'text', component: TextComponent, children: [
      { path: '**', component: TextComponent }
    ] },
```

So far so good.  Everything invokes **TextComponent** as intended.  However I am not sure how best to get the full sub-path of the URL that got to me.   By poking around in the console I found the following seems to work:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.url = this.route.snapshot._routerState.url;
```

and I get the string that starts with '/text/'.  I can go with that but I can't find any documentation that says this is the right property to use.  Further I am not sure a property that starts with an underscore (**_routerState** in this case) is intended to be used this way.

Can anyone guide me on the right path?  (pun intended).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple workaround, you can use `window.location.pathname`. Try running that in you typescipt file and/or manipulating it to get what you want.

```
console.log(window.location.pathname);
```

**Angular Solution**

I asked a few people I know from NgConf for the Angular way of returning the URL. You need to inject an instance of Router and not ActivatedRoute.

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.router.url);
}
```

Comment: I suppose I should have thought of that myself but I was looking for a "pure Angular" solution. I would still like to find one but your idea seems to be able to work for at least client-side operation.

Comment: @AlanObject I got you a better solution